# Can I store a value between executions of a Symfony2 command?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I already know I can't just store it as a protected variable on the Command Class itself (I tried it and that doesn't work). Is there a way to store data between executions of a command without storing that information in the database or writing to a file?

Basically, I'm running a command through cron every 2 minutes, but I want to set a flag that changes every time I run the command.

The following doesn't work, as the protected variable is initialized to `snc_redis.dashboard1` every time I run the command.

```
protected $redisDb = 'snc_redis.dashboard1';

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    if ( $this->redisDb == 'snc_redis.dashboard1') {
        $this->redisDb = 'snc_redis.dashboard2';
    }
    else {
        $this->redisDb = 'snc_redis.dashboard1';
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could store it in some kind of in-memory cache. Have you heard of Memcache?

Comment: Yeah, I've used memcache before, but not directly. I could totally store the value in the redis db somewhere, I was just wondering if there was a way built into symfony to persist properties between command executions?

Comment: Each Php execution has a completely clear context so unless you save to disk or memory al the generated information on each execution just disappears.

Comment: I think actually for my case I'd be better off using one redis db for retrieving data, and then migrating data from my one db to the other so I only read from one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I already know I can't just store it as a protected variable on the Command Class itself (I tried it and that doesn't work).

This is because each time you run the command it's a new process.

> Is there a way to store data between executions of a command without storing that information in the database or writing to a file?

**No.**

Again, each command is run in a separate process, so there's no memory shared between them. Event storing your stuff with APCu won't work (for the same reason).

If you want to persist something between runs you'll need to store it some kind of cache that can be shared between processes (like filesystem, database, redis/memcached etc).